# Loop over pandas dataframe and assign results of a list to another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format:

```
       values
id        
121    [Akjhks,Bsdfjhi,Idsfaf,Akjhks]
345    [Lkhiuy,Eqiyeri,Jewruq]
```

For unique values in every id, I would need to take the id and append it to a resultant pandas dataframe in the below format.

```
value_list    Constant_#
Akjhks        AK
Bsdfjhi       AK
Idsfaf        AK
Lkhiuy        AK
Eqiyeri       AK
Jewruq        AK
```

I could retrieve it using a specific value in value_list but not across the entire dataframe.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why all constant is AK ?

Comment: @BENY: Its the constant that is needed in the result dataframe. Does not have logic for that.

Comment: I guess the question is what is the `result dataframe`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
out = df.explode('values').drop_duplicates()
```